# Class 'Redis' not found in Lumen

Tags: php, redis, lumen

- Lumen Version: 6.0
- PHP Version: 7.2
- Database Driver & Version: MySql 5.7, Redis

[image]

**Code**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

Redis::set($key, $data, 'EX', $expiry);
```

**in app.php**

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();

$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);

$app->configure('database');
```

Using the above code gives **Class 'Redis' not found** error. This error occurs only when the below packages are installed.

```
"illuminate/redis": "^6.5",
"illuminate/mail": "^6.5",
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^6.0",
```

With below packages which has lower versions it works without any error/issues.

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^5.8.*",
"illuminate/redis": "^5.8",
"illuminate/mail": "^5.8",
```

So why is it giving error when packages are upgraded.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be well documented in the Lumen docs, but I suspect things are the same as with Laravel core - you have to install [the phpRedis extension](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) or the `predis/predis` package if you can't install the extension. See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redis#introduction.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `Laravel 8`, in the `database.php` file, replace the following line:

```
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis')
```

to:

```
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis')
```

then, add the `predis` dependency with `composer`:

```
composer require predis/predis
```

Answer (score 10):

You can modify config/database.php.

because lumen6 redis default drive used phpredis.

add .env file like this.

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you set up the PHP Redis extension and enable it.

Even after you do that, you will need to register an alias for Redis in your app.php file. It's clear that you referenced it with your use statement, but that is only visible in the class you are "using" it. The PHP Redis connector will need to reference it from somewhere globally, which is in the app.php file. Laravel comes with this already set-up, but unfortunately Lumen doesn't.

To be safe, wrap it with a check on class existence.

This is how I fixed the problem.

```php
#You already have this:
$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);

#Add the following right below
if (!class_exists('Redis')) {
    class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis', 'Redis');
}
```

Comment: You can simply use apt-get install php7.X-redis to get the extension set-up. Just restart the web service after installing and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

My steps to fix that in Lumen 7:

- install "illuminate/redis" package: `composer require illuminate/redis:"^7.0"`
- install "php-redis" on my CentOS7: `yum --enablerepo=epel -y install php-pecl-redis`
- install "predis" package: `composer require predis/predis:"^1.0"`
- change the redis client to "predis" (by default its "phpredis"): `'client' => 'predis'`. So the config is:

  ```
  'redis' => [
          'cluster' => false,
          'client' => 'predis',
          'default' => [
              'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
              'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
              'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
          ],
      ]
  ```